# Recording values of radio buttons in a db(php)

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have a page of questions that have two options as radio buttons.Each Question has a form tag.Now i want to store the values checked by the user to a database through a single function in ***php***.How to do it?
My html code is as follows:

```
    <li>Question1 </li>
  <br /><form>A.     
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="1ARadioButton" value="1ARadioButton" />
    <label for="1ARadioButton">Answer1</label><br /><br />
  B.    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="1BRadioButton" value="1BRadioButton" />
    <label for="1BRadioButton"> Answer2</label>
    </form><br /><br />
  <li>Question2</li>
  <br /><form>A. 
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="2ARadioButton" value="2ARadioButton" />
    <label for="2ARadioButton">Answer1</label>
     <br /><br />
  B.     
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="2BRadioButton" value="2BRadioButton" />
    <label for="2BRadioButton">Answer2</label>
     </form><br /><br />
  <li>Question3</li>
  <br /><form>A.     
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="3ARadioButton" value="3ARadioButton" />
    <label for="3ARadioButton">Answer1</label>
     <br /><br />
   B.    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="3BRadioButton" value="3BRadioButton" />
    <label for="3BRadioButton">Answer2</label>
     </form><br /><br />
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the same name on all your radio buttons, so you're only going to get the value of the LAST radio button that's checked off. You're going to be recording the same answer for ALL questions (which is usually C, right?).

element IDs are **NOT** used for form submissions. They're used only for DOM operations. On HTML forms, only the `name` and `value` type attributes are relevant for the form submission process.

What you should have is:

```
Question 1:
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option_A" />
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option_B" />
Question 2:
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option_A" />
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option_B" />
etc...
```

As for storing them in the database, that's the same as storing any other form-data in a database. Get the radio's value with `$_POST['question1']` or whatever, and do the usual escaping/query building/inserting.